# What's the difference between "update" and "update_idletasks"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

From the `effbot.org` documentation, we have the following about the [`update`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201105231837id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method) function:

> Processes all pending events, calls event callbacks, completes any
> pending geometry management, redraws widgets as necessary, and calls
> all pending idle tasks. This method should be used with care, since it
> may lead to really nasty race conditions if called from the wrong
> place (from within an event callback, for example, or from a function
> that can in any way be called from an event callback, etc.). When in
> doubt, use `update_idletasks` instead.

On the other hand, there's this about the [`update_idletasks`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201105231837id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) function:

> Calls all pending idle tasks, without processing any other events.
> This can be used to carry out geometry management and redraw widgets
> if necessary, without calling any callbacks.

As far as I understood, both *call all pending idle tasks*, *complete any pending geometry management* and *redraw widgets as necessary*. The only difference I see is that `update` *processes all pending events* and *calls event callbacks*. That's why we should not call `update` from within an even callback, I suppose.

However, I have seen [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop?answertab=active#tab-top) where `update_idletasks` and `update` are used one after the other, and I can't understand the reason, since theoretically `update` does everything `update_idletasks` does.

What exactly are these *pending events* and the *idle tasks* the documentation is talking about? What are the differences and relations?

That being answered, in what real circumstances should I use `update` over `update_idletasks`? Concrete examples are also appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> The only difference I see is that update processes all pending events
>   and calls event callbacks. That's why we should not call update from
>   within an even callback, I suppose.

You are correct on both accounts.

What are pending events? Events scheduled with `after`, mostly. And, as you also mentioned in your question, events that trigger a redraw.

The circumstances when you should use `update` over `update_idletasks`? Almost never. In all honesty, my pragmatic answer is "never call `update` unless calling `update_idletasks` doesn't do enough".

The important thing to remember is that `update` blocks until *all* events are processed. In effect, that means you have a `mainloop` nested inside a `mainloop`. It's never a good idea to have an infinite loop inside an infinite loop.

If you see examples where one is called after the other, you're looking at bad examples. Honestly, there's absolutely no reason whatsoever to do that. A lot of code I see calls `update` way more often than it ever should.

Comment: I followed this advise for a long time. However I discovered a **Close Button** wasn't working inside of a 10 second loop. The reason was `update_idletasks()` had to be changed to `update()` and then the button worked. `Escape` and `WM_DELETE` were also bound to close function and they didn't work either until `.update()` was used.