# How to bind async method to a keystroke in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5, python-3.6, python-asyncio

Consider the following example:

```
import asyncio
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_widgets()
        self._configure_bindings() # I believe it is not possible 
                                   # to do this if the method needs 
                                   # to be async as well

    def create_widgets(self):
        pass

    def _configure_bindings(self):
        self.bind('<F5>', self.spam) # what's the proper way?
                                     # does this method need to be async as well?

    async def spam(self, event):
        await self.do_something()

    async def do_something():
        pass

async def run_tk(root):
    try:
        while True:
            root.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(.01)
    except tk.TclError as e:
        if "application has been destroyed" not in e.args[0]:
            raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_tk(app))
```

What is the proper way to bind async method to a keystroke in tkinter?
I've tried something like:

```
 self.bind('<F5>', self.spam)
 self.bind('<F5>', await self.spam)
 self.bind('<F5>', await self.spam())
 self.bind('<F5>', lambda event: await self.spam(event))
```

...and a bunch of other combinations, but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tkinter` itself is asynchronous thanks to event loop, the [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method and the [bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

However, if you trying to stick with [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) it's also possible, but first let's consider what you tried.

Your first try is obviously a fail, because you trying to call `spam` as a generic function, when it's a [`coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines). Your other tries are more correct than a first, but `await coroutine` or `yield from coroutine` can be used to start a coroutine from another coroutine only, so it fails again.

So the proper way of start that beast is *a scheduling of its execution* with a self-explanatory method [`ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) (or old [`async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async), which is just a deprecated alias).

Try this example:

```
import asyncio
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._configure_bindings()

    def _configure_bindings(self):
        self.bind('<F5>', lambda event: asyncio.ensure_future(self.spam(event)))

    async def spam(self, event):
        await self.do_something()
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('%s executed!' % self.spam.__name__)

    async def do_something(self):
        print('%s executed!' % self.do_something.__name__)

async def run_tk(root):
    try:
        while True:
            root.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(.01)
    except tk.TclError as e:
        if "application has been destroyed" not in e.args[0]:
            raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_tk(app))
```

Also, I think that it's worth to mention [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158811/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-update-idletasks) question, since you use an `update` method.

Comment: Cyn you explain why you use `update()` instead of `update_idletasks()`? see [Tkinter-Docs](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html)

Comment: @buhtz, this line originates directly from the question. Also I mentioned a topic to that “problem” in my answer. Practically, in the context of that question, there’s no difference.