# In python's threading library, is there a method that can be used to close all created threads in execution?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I currently have a very extensive python project (>8000 lines) that uses Threads to execute several operations. It also uses tkinter to make a GUI application, and before you point that out, I'm very aware that tkinter and threading don't mix very well, but I hope that's not what is causing my trouble here.

`from threading import Thread`

The root of my problem is that even after closing my Tkinter Application, it still runs on task manager, never completely closing. I believe this is caused by Threads still active and waiting to update widgets within the code, even after the main root is destroyed.

Since the project is so large, before I go make a python list containing all the thread objects to then call .close on each of them upon the closure of the main root, **is there any command within the threading library that can in one line close all of the current active Threads?**

Also, since I code as a hobby and I'm still very new to python, am I doing something very wrong or using incorrect nomenclature to communicate? lol

Thank you very much!

Also my version of everything (python+libraries) is the latest.

--What I'm about to do and what I expect--

I'm about to create a global list and then put all thread objects within it to then call .close on each of them.

I will probably change the "WM_DELETE_WINDOW" protocol to run a function that does "for obj in thread_names_list, obj.close()", before destroying the root.

I expect this to solve the task manager problem. Hopefully...

======Update======

An example of how I call threads

```
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk
import time
def main():
    global root, button_foo
    root = tk.Tk() 
    root.state('zoomed')
    button_foo = tk.Button(root, text='Hello')
    button_foo.place(x= 200, y= 200) 
    Thread(target=updates_button).start()
    root.mainloop()
 
def updates_button():
    time.sleep(10)
    button_foo.config(text='Time is passing...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Python threads do not have a close() function

Comment: If you make them `daemon` threads, all daemon threads are abruptly killed when the application exits.  You're aware that threads cannot update UI objects, right?  Are you using `callafter` to do the updates?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm targetting a function with threading.Thread, and that function updates widgets via .config or .itemconfig. There are often time.sleeps within those threaded functions. I'm unfamiliar with `callafter`

Comment: I was also unfamiliar with the `daemon` threads until now, and now that I'm searching about them, I find the concept very interesting! For sure I'm looking deep into those, so thank you for mentioning them!

Comment: Updated the question to include a minimal example of how I use threads within my code. Perhaps it's also important to add that most of my threads are used to update Canvas Image objects. Some of those threads end by looping, calling themselves, so the animations loop.

Comment: What you are doing is NOT VALID.  Maybe it works sometimes, on some platforms, but for example it won't ever work on MacOS.  You CANNOT touch any GUI components from a non-main thread.  That's a rule that you must embed in your brain.  What you have above is the reason the `after` method was invenited.  Do `button_foo.after( 10000, updates)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for warning me, as well as anyone who comes to this question in the future, about this, @TimRoberts! I currently code on Windows, but I do intend the project to cross platform later on, so your insights will surely save me a lot of time and effort in the future. From now on, I will inform myself more regarding this topic, and I'm glad I came to ask this question!

Answer (score 0):

There is already a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread) about how to kill a thread. There are many methods to do so. Setting `Thread( ..., daemon=True)` might be enough but is generally considered  a bad pattern.
If refactoring the 8000+ lines of code in your project is viable, it would be better to use

> [concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), a higher level interface to push tasks to a background thread

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import tkinter as tk
import time

def main():
    global root, button_foo
    root = tk.Tk() 
    root.state('zoomed')
    # ...
    
    # create thread pool and let the context manager to shut it down
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor: 
        # submit updates_button to a background thread
        executor.submit(updates_button) 
        # main thread continues to run the mainloop
        root.mainloop()

 
# ...
```

This  uses the context manager to automatically create and shutdown the thread pool. You can also manage it manually for better controlling how the threads stop. Call  [`executor.shutdown`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown) with options like `wait` and `cancel_futures`.

The `update_button` function also needs refactoring because you should not update the GUI outside the main thread. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63367151/6238076) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289276/6238076)  SO answers for proper ways to update the Tk widget.

Comment: *it is generally considered a bad pattern* -- By who?  Can you cite any references?

Comment: @TimRoberts By the author of the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread) that I cited. "It is generally a bad pattern to kill a thread abruptly", and according to the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects), "daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown".

Comment: Yes, BUT in this case the application is known to be dying.  Terminating abruptly seems the appropriate action.  We don't care about work that was left undone.