# Calling async function from button command Tkinter

Tags: python, asynchronous, tkinter

I want to call an async function from a Tkinter button command, or rather want to let the function run asynchronously, so that the tkinter window is responsive. 
I've tried `command = open_async` in the Button, where `open_async` was declared like so `async def open_async():`, but it gave me an error "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'open_async' was never awaited
self.tk.mainloop(n)".

 If I just used `def async():`, the code would still run synchronously, thus the UI will be unresponsive. (`async()` contains some other asynchronous operation inside too, using `asyncio` and stuff).

Anyone knows how to resolve this? I don't want to create threads too.
Thanks

Comment: async functions need an event loop to be executed which in turn needs a thread. You can either mix it with the mainloop of tkinter or run it in a separate thread. Some helpful approaches are at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895765/use-asyncio-and-tkinter-or-another-gui-lib-together-without-freezing-the-gui

Comment: Why do you want to run the function asynchronously? If you want to implement some kind of loop, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801) is the proper way of doing it. If that still doesn't help, you can use threads.

Answer (score 0):

Answering very Late but Use command=lambda : asyncio.run(open_async())

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer does not work: gives error *asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop*

Comment: [This is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77580805/3070181) that shows how this can bu done as minimal reproduceable example