# How to call an async function from a tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter, asynchronous

I want to call an asynchronous function from a tkinter button

```
import asyncio
import time
import tkinter as tk

async def gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    timer = tk.Button(root, text='Timer', command=lambda: asyncio.run(wait()))
    # timer = tk.Button(root, text='Timer', command=wait())
    timer.pack()
    root.mainloop()

async def sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def wait():
    start = time.time()
    await sleep()
    print(f'Elapsed: {time.time() - start}')

async def main():
    await wait()

asyncio.run(main())
asyncio.run(gui())
```

If I use the line

```
    timer = tk.Button(root, text='Timer', command=wait())
```

I get the error

> coroutine 'wait' was never awaited

but if I use the line

```
    timer = tk.Button(root, text='Timer', command=lambda: asyncio.run(wait()))
```

I get the error

> asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

What's the resolution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of this is to understand which functions come under the async umbrella. This is simpler and resolves all the issues. Note that only the *sleep* function is asynchronous, and the *wait* function contains the *async* call

```
asyncio.run(sleep())
```

The code is now:

```
import asyncio
import time
import tkinter as tk

def gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    timer = tk.Button(root, text="Timer", command=wait)
    timer.pack()
    root.mainloop()

def wait():
    start = time.time()
    asyncio.run(sleep())
    print(f'Elapsed: {time.time() - start}')

async def sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

def main():
    wait()

main()
gui()
```