# plt.show not working on another thread, only on main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to write a python script that reads a CSV file and generates a PNG file with some graphs with GUI interface. The code is below:

```
from matplotlib import peplos as plot
from tkinter.constants import LEFT, RIGHT, S
import tkinter as tk, time, threading, random, queue

class GuiPart(object):
    def __init__(self, master, queue, client_instance):
        self.queue = queue
        self.button1 =  tk.Button(master, text="Command", padx=10, 
                        pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42",   command=client_instance.start_thread1)

    self.button1.pack()

    def processIncoming(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            pass

class ThreadedClient(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
   
        self.master = master
   
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.running = True

    
        self.gui = GuiPart(master, self.queue, self)
    
        self.periodic_call()

    
    def start_thread1(self):
    
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.worker_thread1)
        thread1.start()

    def periodic_call(self):
        self.master.after(200, self.periodic_call)
        self.gui.processIncoming()
        if not self.running:
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)

    def worker_thread1(self):

   
        if self.running:
   
    
            time.sleep(rand.random() * 1.5)

            x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
            y = [4, 3, 2, 1]

            plt.plot(x, y)
            plt.show()

    def end_application(self):
         self.running = False

rand = random.Random()
root = tk.Tk()
client = ThreadedClient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I haven't shown the all way how to read the CSV, all the plotting, but only where the issue is. I am choosing this approach as with I don't want the GUI to freeze with large CSV files. To problem that I am facing now is if I want to do plt.show() instead will not work telling me I am in the main thread. I tried to move it in the main thread but the freezing issue will reappear. I have also tried to add Toplevel both in main and in another thread without any success. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have read more about the issue and it seems it is a Tkinter problem and not a matplotlib one. Would it be possble then to do all the operations in the worker thread and the plt.show only in the main thread? If yes, can someone show me how to that? I have tried to find an answer for many days... thank you!

Comment: please provide a reproductible example, with the imports and necessary methods. What does `periodic_call` do?

Comment: @FlavioMoraes Sorry I forgot to add the 'periodic_call'; now it is there. I have added the imports as well.

Comment: it is a guess but what if you create the figure before starting the threat? Just before defining `thread1` you can create the figure with `self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()` and instead of `plt.plot(x,y)` use `self.ax.plot(x,y)` followed by `self.fig.savefig('test.png')`. I didn't received any warning by doing this, but I don't know about the freezing issue

Comment: @FlavioMoraes The problem is not with the fig.savefig as this I know is working. I want to use plt.show() instead and this gives me headaches and also I want to start the function by clicking a button.

Comment: I see, but I still believe that my idea holds. The idea is to create the plot before the thread and just update it during the thread.

Comment: @FlavioMoraes You are right, it is working if I create the figure just before defining the thread. However, the freezing problem is still present if I use the method, so this is not helping me. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: By freezing you mean that the widow stops working while you perform another task? Maybe you can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895765/use-asyncio-and-tkinter-or-another-gui-lib-together-without-freezing-the-gui

Comment: @FlavioMoraes yes, by freezing I meant window stops responding. Thank you for the link. I am using the same approach with a main thread and a worker thread. If I put plt.show() in the worker thread, it is not working: if I put outside of worker thread, it is freezing.