# How to run tkinter keypress event loop and the canvas update at the same time without delay

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a game that is similar to piano tiles and I am having issue with animating the game and event loop at the same time. I am trying to split the event loop that check for the KeyPress and the game animation so that it will be smooth and not slow down when I spam a keybind. Can I check if there's a way for me to use asyncio on the event loop so that the animation will not slow down? Thank you.

game.py

```
import threading
import tkinter
import main
import time
from playsound import playsound


def open_file(music_file):
    """Open a music file."""
    with open(music_file, 'r') as file:
        return file.read()


class Game:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.game_menu_sc = None
        self.place_to_hit = []
        self.lines = []
        self.number_of_keys = 12
        self.items = None
        self.points = 0
        self.root = root
        self.clickable_area = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7, 'i': 8, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11}


    def game_screen(self):
        """Create the game screen of the application."""
        for widget in self.root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        game_menu_sc = tkinter.Canvas(self.root)
        game_menu_sc.configure(bg='white')
        screen_width, screen_height = main.get_screen_size(self.root)
        width, height = main.scale_to_screen_size(screen_width, screen_height)
        game_menu_sc.bind('<KeyPress>', self.keyup)

        game_menu_sc.place(width=width, height=height)
        game_menu_sc.focus_set()
        for i in range(self.number_of_keys):
            line = game_menu_sc.create_line(i * int(width / self.number_of_keys), 0,
                                            i * int(width / self.number_of_keys), height, fill='black')
            self.lines.append(line)
            place_to_hit = game_menu_sc.create_rectangle(i * int(width / self.number_of_keys), int(height - 50),
                                                         i * int(width / self.number_of_keys) + int(
                                                             width / self.number_of_keys), int(height), fill='black')
            self.place_to_hit.append(place_to_hit)
        self.game_menu_sc = game_menu_sc
        self.animate_game(game_menu_sc, width)
        return True

    def animate_game(self, canvas, width):
        """Animate the game."""
        self.items = self.play_music('music1.txt', width)
        while True:
            for item in self.items:
                canvas.move(item, 0, 1)
            canvas.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)
            if not self.items:
                print('points  {}'.format(self.points))
                break

    def keyup(self, event):
        """Handle keyup events."""
        list_of_keycodes = [65, 83, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 186, 222, 13]
        for index, keycode in enumerate(list_of_keycodes):
            if keycode == event.keycode:
                threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=(f'assets/{index + 1 }.wav',), daemon=True).start()
                # winsound.PlaySound(f'assets/{index + 1}.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
                if self.get_collision(index):
                    self.points += 1
                    print('collision')

    def get_collision(self, index):
        """Check if there is a collision and remove the object if there's a collision."""
        p = self.game_menu_sc.coords(self.place_to_hit[index])
        collision = self.game_menu_sc.find_overlapping(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3])
        collision = list(collision)
        collision_new = list(collision)

        for item in collision_new:
            if item in self.place_to_hit or item in self.lines:
                collision.remove(item)
        if len(collision) != 0:
            self.items.remove(collision[0])
            self.game_menu_sc.delete(collision[0])
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def play_music(self, music_file, width):
        """Create the rectangles based on the music file."""
        music = open_file(music_file)
        notes = music.split(',')
        list_of_items = []
        for note in notes:
            index, keys = note.split(':')
            for items in keys:
                i = self.clickable_area[items]
                rectangles = self.create_rectangle(i * int(width / self.number_of_keys) + 1, -float(index) * 50,
                                                   i * int(width / self.number_of_keys) +
                                                   int(width / self.number_of_keys) - 1, -float(index) * 50 + 50)
                list_of_items.append(rectangles)
        return list_of_items

    def create_rectangle(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        """Create rectangles."""
        place_to_hit = self.game_menu_sc.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='black')
        return place_to_hit
```

music1.txt

```
1:a,2:b,3:ab,4:df,5:dl,6:ab,7:ah,8:hj,8:la,9:ga,10:la,11:fd
```

I have tried using asyncio and followed the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896365/18043570 but I could not even load into the game as I get this error

```
DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

I have seen multiple solution on how to run both tkinter and an additional function not related to tkinter using asyncio, but I could not find anything related to the event loops

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep` or `while True` loops when using `tkinter`. If you want a `tkinter` loop use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801)

Comment: I tried to follow that but my game does not even run, and I don't think that would help with my problem right?