# Emitting event from client to server using python-socketio is extremely slow

Tags: python, python-sockets, python-socketio

I'm using `python-socketio` for the first time, I have a simple `AsyncServer` that looks like this.

```
import socketio
from aiohttp import web

sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print("Connected")

@sio.event
def set_name(sid, name):
    print("Set name: " + name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.run_app(app)
```

And I have a client that looks like this.

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.AsyncClient()

async def start():
    await sio.connect("http://localhost:8080", transports=['websocket'])
    await sio.wait()

async def set_username(name):
    await sio.emit("set_name", name)
```

On the client, I use `asyncio.run` on the `start` function, and it connects successfully and instantly. However, later on when I do the same with the `set_username` function, it's EXTREMELY slow and takes a minute for the event to be recognized on the server-side.

I've tried using event loops in `asyncio` with no luck. I searched for similar problems on the Internet, found similar ones but none of their solutions worked for me.

Comment: Could you please specify the versions of your dependencies?  (pip freeze output should do the thing )

> `EXTREMELY slow and takes a minute for the event to be recognized on the server side.`

So the message comes into the server and then the handler `def set_name(sid, name):` takes a minute to process?

Comment: @IDobrodushniy I'm not sure if the handler is the one lagging or if it doesn't even reach the server. All I know is that the `print("Set name")` takes some time(upwards of 15-20 seconds). As for dependencies, I'm running `aiohttp==3.8.6, python-socketio==5.9.0`

Comment: @MohamedElDahtowry You said "when I do the same with the set_username function", but you are not showing exactly what you did. That is not clear, because the `start()` function does not return. Please provide a complete client that calls `set_username`.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg
I simply have a method that calls `asyncio.run(socket_service.set_username(self.name.get()))`

Comment: That is wrong. Asyncio.run is called once to start an async application, you shouldn't be calling it again.

Comment: But my `set_username` function has `async` and `await` in them, how can I run them without asyncio?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mentioning the versions of the libraries you have, this helped me to double check.

You mentioned you tried to run this code either with `eventloop` or `asyncio.run` and both had no success.
The way you run your client is crucial here as the setup on the server is okay. You said at first you run `connect` and then you run `set_username`.

Not sure how exactly the `set_username` got triggered in your cases, but in the code you shared it simply isn't.

Please see the two scripts attached below as an example of how it could lok like and let me know if they work for you. What code does should be clear from the doc strings I hope.

```
# server.py

import socketio
from aiohttp import web

sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
app = web.Application()

sio.attach(app)


@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    """ Handle the connect event."""
    print(f"Sid {sid} connected.")


@sio.event
async def set_name(sid, name):
    """ Handle `set_name` event and sned a message back to the client that it was acknowledged."""
    print(f"Sid {sid} says: {name}.\nSending acknowledgment to {sid}.\n")
    await sio.emit("server-message", name, to=sid)


@sio.on("client_update")
async def handle_client_update(sid, value):
    """ Handle the `client_update` event and log the message."""
    print(f"Sid {sid} sends an update: {value}.\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.run_app(app)
```

```
# client.py

import asyncio
import random

import socketio

sio = socketio.AsyncClient()


async def main():
    """
    Connect to the server and then waits for events from it.
    """
    await sio.connect("ws://localhost:8080/", transports=['websocket'], )

    while True:
        await sio.emit("set_name", random.choice(("John", "Mike", "Bob")))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


@sio.on("server-message")
async def get_from_server(name: str):
    """
    Get `server-message` event from server and print the log.
    """
    print(f"Server acknowledged that `{name}` was received.")


@sio.on("connect")
async def handle_connect_ack_from_server():
    """
    The handler will react to successful connection being established.
    """
    await sio.emit("client_update", "Thank you!")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main()) # you can replace me with `asyncio.run` - doesn't matter.
```

At first run the `python3 server.py` and then `python3 client.py`. After that you should see the logs both on the server and on the client:

- Client sending `set_name` event every 1 second, so server will be logging it.
- Server sending `server-message` to the client, so client will be logging it.

I hope this works

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, that code didn't work. It did print that the names were acknowledged 4 times(which I think it should be printing it infinitely since there's a `while: True`?) and when I tried emitting `set_name` later on it completely stopped working.  Also, I forgot to clarify, I'm using `tkinter` and there's an Entry field where the user can write their name and then it emits to the server. My original code works, just extremely slow. After some testing, I found out it's a client-side issue, not a server-side. Furthermore, switch to standard "non-asyncio" worked.

Comment: Yeah, the detail about environment your client is executed in is important. 

Unless you absolutely need to use an async client, I would suggest to just use a synchronous version of the client while it fits in a mix with TKinter.

If it is necessary, unfortunately I can't help without more details.

I would also not suggest to use asyncio with Tkinter overall https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895765/use-asyncio-and-tkinter-or-another-gui-lib-together-without-freezing-the-gui

Comment: I usually use Node.js, and basically what I wanted is to wait till the server have received the user name before switching to the next page. This project is will only be running in a local environment so I don't think it'll be an issue. But I'm still confused on why it takes such a long time for sending something as simple as a name. I switched on the logging and it takes some time on "sending packet". I also made the same server with node.js, which the problem persisted so I knew it's a client-side issue.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is in how asyncio loop on the client side is getting execution time to run the message. Basically as soon as you try to emit, it yields the control back(to Tkinter environment you have) and apparently gets it back much later. 

Python GUIs on top of event loops are not so advanced as javascript in the browser.