# Python custom tkinter and Asyncio and Threading with custom functions

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pytube, customtkinter

Basically, I am trying to make an asynchronous GUI.
I have made 2 classes that use the pytube package. The Video class represents a video and when it's constructor runs it searches for a video. The _Playlist class represents a Playlist (a list of videos):

```
class Video:
    def __init__(self, url) -> None:

        try:
            self.yt = YouTube(url)
        except exceptions.VideoPrivate:
            raise CustomVideoException(ExceptionCode.PRIVATE_VIDEO)
        except exceptions.VideoRegionBlocked:
            raise CustomVideoException(ExceptionCode.REGION_BLOCKED)
        except exceptions.VideoUnavailable:
            raise CustomVideoException(ExceptionCode.VIDEO_UNAVAILABLE)
        except exceptions.PytubeError:
            raise CustomVideoException(ExceptionCode.PY_TUBE_ERROR)
        except Exception:
            raise CustomVideoException(ExceptionCode.MAJOR_ERROR)

        video_streams = self.yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
        audio_streams = self.yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True)
        self.video_resolutions = list()
        self.audio_resolutions = list()

        self.title = self.yt.title
        self.author = self.yt.author
        self.views = self.yt.views

        for stream in video_streams:
            self.video_resolutions.append({"_type": stream.mime_type, "res": stream.resolution})
        for stream in audio_streams:
            self.audio_resolutions.append({"_type": stream.mime_type, "abr": stream.abr})

    def _download(self, selected_res: str, on_progress_callback):
        # return self.yt.streams.get_by_resolution(selected_res)
        self.yt.register_on_progress_callback(on_progress_callback)
        self.yt.streams.get_by_resolution(selected_res).download()

    def on_callback(self, stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
        total_size = stream.filesize
        bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
        percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100

        print(round(percentage_of_completion))

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'VIDEO:\nTitle: {self.title}, Author: {self.author}, Views: {self.views}\nVideo Resolutions: ' \
               f'{self.video_resolutions}\nAudio Resolutions: {self.audio_resolutions}'


class _Playlist:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.videos = list()

    def read_playlist(self, url: str):
        temp_playlist = Playlist(url)
        for video_url in temp_playlist.video_urls:
            self.videos.append({"code": video_url.split("=")[1], "video": Video(video_url)})

    def add_video(self, url: str):
        if "youtube.com" not in url:
            raise CustomVideoException(ExceptionCode.WRONG_URL)
        if "watch?v=" not in url:
            raise CustomVideoException(ExceptionCode.WRONG_URL)
        self.videos.append({"code": url.split("=")[1], "video": Video(url)})

    def print_video_urls(self):
        for v in self.videos:
            print(v["video"])
```

The thing is that I want to be able to create an object of the `Video` class and run the _download function in video class asynchronously via a ctk.Button.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895765/use-asyncio-and-tkinter-or-another-gui-lib-together-without-freezing-the-gui) question I tried to apply it to my code. Currently I have make a class "App" that represents my main application and I added a list with tasks `self.tasks` where all my to do tasks are stored. The problem is that when I press run the function `do_search_video()` it does nothing.
The task is created but apparently never runs?

My current code is this:

```
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, _loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop, interval: float = (1 / 120)):
        super().__init__()
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")
        # center window to the screen
        app_width = 900
        app_height = 500
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width/2)
        y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height/2)
        self.geometry(f"{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")

        self.i = 0
        self.loop = _loop
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        self.tasks = list()
        self.tasks.append(self.loop.create_task(self.updater(interval)))

        self.url_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self, width=int(app_width*0.8))
        self.url_entry.bind(sequence="<Return>", command=self.do_search_video)
        self.url_entry.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

        self.playlist_frame = PlaylistFrame(self)
        self.playlist_frame.add_video_frame("Limmy's Show - Water", 4868637, "LANman247")
        self.playlist_frame.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        self.mainloop()
        # self.btn = ctk.CTkButton(self, text='Change Label', command=self.do_on_click)

    def do_search_video(self, *args):
        self.tasks.append(self.loop.create_task(self.search_video()))

    async def search_video(self):
        try:
            self.playlist_frame.playlist.add_video(self.url_entry.get())

            self.playlist_frame.add_video_frame(
                title=self.playlist_frame.playlist.videos[-1]["video"].title,
                author=self.playlist_frame.playlist.videos[-1]["video"].author,
                views=self.playlist_frame.playlist.videos[-1]["video"].views,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    async def updater(self, interval):
        while True:
            self.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
```

I have also tried running the `search_video` function like a coroutine (this is how I understand it):

```
def do_search_video(self, *args):
        self.tasks.append(self.loop.create_task(asyncio.run(self.search_video())))

    @asyncio.coroutine
    async def search_video(self):
        try:
            self.playlist_frame.playlist.add_video(self.url_entry.get())

            self.playlist_frame.add_video_frame(
                title=self.playlist_frame.playlist.videos[-1]["video"].title,
                author=self.playlist_frame.playlist.videos[-1]["video"].author,
                views=self.playlist_frame.playlist.videos[-1]["video"].views,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

When I run it this way I get the actual outcome I want but I also get an error:
`TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got None`
Probably cause I don't initialize a coroutine correctly?

The question is how could this be implied? Am I thinking correctly?
I am fairly new to asyncio and asynchronous programming as it seems.

Thank you for your help in advance

**UPDATE**
I added 2 more elements in my GUI, "test_label" and c_button, and 2 more functions just to see if the label would change asynchronously:

```
self.label_stuck = ctk.StringVar()
        self.label_stuck.set("a label")
        test_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, width=int(app_width * 0.8), textvariable=self.label_stuck)
        test_label.pack()

        c_button = ctk.CTkButton(self, width=int(app_width * 0.2), command=self.do_on_click)
        c_button.pack()

        self.counter = 0

def do_on_click(self):
        self.tasks.append(self.loop.create_task(self.on_click()))

    async def on_click(self):
        self.label_stuck.set(f"{self.counter}")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        self.counter += 1
        self.label_stuck.set(f"{self.counter}")
        self.counter += 1
```

If I remove the line `self.mainloop()` this implementation works. When I press the c_button the label's text changes and after 5 seconds it changes again and GUI remains responsive.
Still though I cannot do it with my functions. It there a way to implement the same concept with the Video class?
Maybe by using threading?
Plus, there is this bizarre error when I close the app:

```
while executing
"3080665250440update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "3080636189768check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"3080636189768check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
```

Comment: No asyncio Task can run unless you start the asyncio event loop.  But customtkinter already has an event loop of its own.  Somehow you must run both loops together.  This is possible with tkinter, but a quick glance through the documentation did not suggest that customtkinter can do that.

Comment: @PaulCornelius, I just updated the question. I could figure out how to generally do it. But not in my implementation. Do you think there is a way?

Comment: Instead of running the mainloop from customtkinter, you'll have to run the asyncio loop and call update on the CTk root instance. But it might be easier to use threading.Thread to create a worker. There will be no conflict between the ctk loop and the running thread. I tried handling the tkinter loop myself on one of my projects but it (I) created so may problems. So now I always try to have tkinter.mainloop do it's thing and work arround it with threads.