# How to make Scrollbar work in Tkinter frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a project where I have to display logs in a frame with the help of Tkinter. Here is my code for that particular frame.

```
# frame3 for logs
frame3 = Frame(
    win,
    bg='black',
    width=310,
    height=140,
    padx=0,
    pady=0)
frame3.pack(fill=X, expand=True, padx=(0, 10), pady=0)
frame3.pack_propagate(0)  # stops frame from shrinking
scroll = Scrollbar(frame3)
scroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
```

The **logs are generated and are printed** in that frame. Here is the code for generating and printing logs

```
logs = Label(frame3, text = (time.ctime()), font=("Consolas", 9), bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff")
logs.pack(pady=(0, 0))
```

[image]

The scrollbar is showing but it is somehow not working. The scroll is sliding if I click and slide it with the mouse. I guess there are 3 types of scrollbars in Tkinter (Correct me if I'm wrong).

1. window scrollbar.
2. Frame scrollbar.
3. Label Scrollbar (not sure about that).

I think the problem is that I made is a scrollbar for a frame. But, I need it for Label. Or is there any way by which I can print logs directly onto the frame? Don't know what the actual problem is. Also, is there a way by which I can make it auto scrollable when the logs are generated?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is only one type of scrollbar, and it can't scroll frames or labels. Why are you using labels in a frame rather than a `Text` widget?

Comment: Use a `Text` or `Canvas` so you can link up logs and scrollbar. For now in your case the scrollbar and a frame are independent.

Comment: logs = Text(frame3, height=2, width=30)
logs.pack()
logs.insert(END, time.ctime())

I used this still it's not working. @БогданОпир

Comment: You did not link up the scrollbar and `Text`. That's why that did not work.

Comment: How to link up? @БогданОпир

Comment: `bar.config(command=text.yview)`, `text.config(yscrollcommand=bar.set)`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @БогданОпир Its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using `tkinter.scrolledtext`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = Tk()

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root)
txt['font'] = ('consolas', '12')
txt.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
txt.configure(state=DISABLED)

def log(data):
    txt.configure(state=NORMAL)
    txt.insert(END, data+'\n')
    txt.configure(state=DISABLED)

log('abc')
log('abcde')

root.mainloop()
```

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work when logs are generated on runtime! Only the first log is displayed

Comment: Try using `root.update()` to update the window. Not sure that would help, can't tell why else wouldn't that work.

Comment: Thanks, man this worked. Actually I was putting the pack() method inside the loop!

Comment: @Vraj: Read up on [What's the difference between "update" and "update_idletasks"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29159152/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

`.see("end")` method helps autoscroll.

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.