# Get height/width of tkinter Canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

I am searching for this for ages now. Is it so hard to get the height/width of a Canvas in tkinter?
I want to do something like this:

```py
c = Tk.Canvas(self, heigth=12, width=12)
c.create_oval(0, 0, self.height, self.width)
```

So that I draw a circle with the circumference of the width/height of my canvas.

How come I can't find any attribute like width/height of that canvas?
`c.winfo_width` and `c.winfo_height` wouldn't work, because that only gives me error.

Can you help me? This is really irritating, since even in the constructor there is the attribute `height`and `width`...

Comment: You have to call `<tkinter.Tk>.update` before `winfo_height`.

Comment: Also you said that it gives it *wouldn't work, because that only gives me error*. What is the error traceback?

Comment: @TheLizzard  Funnily enough when I tried your answers solution, afterwards`c.winfo_width` and `c.winfo_height` also worked. But I'll stick with @hussics answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use winfo_reqwidth and winfo_reqheight:

```
root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root, height=120, width=120)
c.create_oval(0, 0, c.winfo_reqheight(), c.winfo_reqwidth())

c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Just saying that this wouldn't always work. `winfo_reqheight` gets the heith the widget requires not the real height. To prove this put the canvas inside a frame: `tk.Frame(root, width=10, height=10)` and call `frame.pack_propagate(False)`

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `<tkinter.Tk>.update` and `<tkinter.Canvas>.pack` before the `winfo_height` like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root, height=120, width=120)
c.pack()

root.update()
c.create_oval(0, 0, c.winfo_height(), c.winfo_width())

root.mainloop()
```

Also parts of this code are stolen from @hussic.

`<tkinter.Tk>.update` makes sure that all tkinter tasks are done. Those tasks can be things like making sure that the geometry manager was reserved the space for the widgets and the widgets are drawn on the screen. Calling `<tkinter.Widget>.update` where `Widget` can be any tkinter widget is the same as calling `<tkinter.Tk>.update` as it will call the same tcl function.

Comment: What does `<tkinter.Tk>.update` mean? AFAIK, `update` is a universal method and can be used on any widget, not just `Tk()`.

Comment: @CoolCloud I will update my answer with an explanation

Comment: What I meant was, the way you said `<tkinter.Tk>.update` makes it seems `update()` can only be called on `Tk()`, was a correction.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me out! But I'll go with @hussic s answer.

Comment: @Sunburst275 its fine I am just showing another option that you have. CoolCloud it calls the same tcl function so it doesn't matter and its conventional to call `<tkinter.Tk>.update`

Comment: I think that in general is better to use update_idletasks() which has less side effects.

Comment: @hussic I had only 1 bug caused by calling `update` instead of `update_idletasks` which I corrected by moving some code around (still using `update`). I can't find a proper explanation online for the technical differences between `update` and `update_idletasks` so I only use `update`.

Comment: This is not enough? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158811/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-update-idletasks

Comment: @hussic I already read that and didn't help much. Also I in this case `update_idletasks` doesn't work because you need to update the window so that geometry manager can give the canvas the space it needs so that `winfo_width` works. Also I disagree with BryanOakley's explanation that *you have a `mainloop` nested inside a `mainloop`* when you use `update`.

Comment: The main difference, i think, is in the callback: if you bind <Configure> to some function, update() calls the function, update_idletask() does not call it. @TheLizzard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229617/discussion-between-thelizzard-and-hussic).

Comment: I think `update()` does the work of `update_idletasks()` and more.

Comment: @CoolCloud I know that but the question is exactly what does `update` do that `update_idletasks` doesn't do. I found [this](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/update.htm) but it's still too vague.