# How Do I Use Multiple Windows In Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I Have used Python Tkinter Is There a Way to use multiple windows in tkinter Can Any one tell pe Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tk.Toplevel()` to create new window in tkinter.

More information is available [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_toplevel.htm)

Example

```
new_win=Toplevel()
```

**Note: if you destroy the main `Tk()` all of the `Toplevel()` attached to that main window will also be destroyed.**

Comment: It might be worth adding a comment that says something like: if you destroy the main `Tk()` all of the `Toplevel()`s attacked to that main window will also be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple instance of `Tk()` -

```
root = Tk()
win = Tk()
```

But multiple instances of `Tk()`  are discouraged, see [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged#:%7E:text=The%20same%20goes%20for%20widgets,Tk%20at%20the%20same%20time.)

The best solution is **[Top Levels](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-toplevel-widget/)**
This is how you make a toplevel widget -

```
toplevel = Toplevel(root, bg, fg, bd, height, width, font, ..)
```

Comment: Windows and tabs have different meanings right? So I thought OP wanted multiple windows and not tabs

Comment: But OP mentions windows

Answer (score 0):

I believe an example is in order.

```py
import tkinter as tk

# primary tkinter window
parent = tk.Tk()
parent.title( "Parent" )

# A child window can be created like so
child = tk.Toplevel( parent )
child.transient( parent )
child.title( "Child" )

# Note the reference to parent when child is created
# The transient method will guarantee the child will ALWAYS be in front of the parent
# Any number of children can be created for every parent

# Complex widgets that have many components require time to instantiate correctly
parent.update_idletasks()

# When a parent is destroyed so will the children

def closer( event ):
    parent.destroy()

# Widgets can be bound to keyboard or mouse inputs
parent.bind( "<Escape>", closer )

parent.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `parent.update_idletasks()` is useless. All of the things it will do will be done when the code execution reaches `parent.mainloop()`.

Comment: @TheLizzard the rem statement mentions complex widgets.

Comment: What widget would need that? All widgets that are part of `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` don't need `.update_idletasks()` to be created correctly. Also can you give an example of a *complex widget*?

Comment: Something with lots of images, scrollbars, children, buttons etc...

Comment: Still doesn't need `.update_idletasks()`. If you have spare time can you please give me a basic minimal example (on something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)) where removing the `.update_idletasks()` will be a problem? Also the documentation never mentions that it initialises the widget/children of that widget.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion

Comment: Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29159152/11106801). `.update_idletasks` is very similar to `.update` as in, it handles things like `.after` scripts. `.update()` does the same thing but it also handles other events as well. `.mainloop()` is very similar to a loop that just calls `.update()`. Therefore your `.update_idletasks` is unneeded and the comment is above that wrong.