# How can I make udate_idletasks work on Mac

Tags: macos, tkinter

I've written a tkinter script with animation, that works fine on Xubuntu, but when I run it on Mac, the animation doesn't work.  Here's a little script that demonstrates the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=200, width = 200)
canvas.pack()

this = canvas.create_rectangle(25,25, 75, 75, fill='blue')
that = canvas.create_rectangle(125, 125, 175, 175, fill = 'red')

def blink(event):
    global this, that
    for _ in range(9):
        canvas.itemconfigure(this, fill='red')
        canvas.itemconfigure(that, fill = 'blue')
        canvas.update_idletasks()
        sleep(.4)
        this, that = that, this
        
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', blink)

root.mainloop()
```

This draws a red square and a blue square on a canvas.  When the user clicks the canvas, the squares repeatedly switch colors.  On Xubuntu, it works as intended.

On Mac, when I click the canvas, I get spinning beach ball, and after a few seconds, we see that squares have switched colors, because they switch colors an odd number of times in the code.

It seems to me that update_idletasks isn't working.  Is there some way to fix this?  I am running python 3.9.5 with Tk 8.6 on Big Sur.

Comment: Avoid using `sleep()` anyway, instead integrate with `after()`

Comment: @CoolCloud Good point.  It's been a long time since I last did something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you can do is avoid tasks that will block the `mainloop`, in this case `time.sleep()`. So your code can be remade by emulating a `for` loop with `after`, and I see nothing that stops this general code from running OS independent:

```py
count = 0 # Think of this as the `_` in for _ in range(9)
def blink(event=None):
    global this, that, count
    
    if count < 9: # Basically repeats everytime `count` is less than 9, like a for loop
        canvas.itemconfigure(this, fill='red')
        canvas.itemconfigure(that, fill='blue')

        this, that = that, this
        count += 1 # Increase count
        root.after(400,blink) # Repeat this code block every 400 ms or 0.4 seconds
    else: 
        count = 0 # After it is 9, set it to 0 for the next click to be processed
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `update` instead of `update_idletasks` works on both platforms.  It's my understanding though, that the latter is much preferred.  See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158811/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-update-idletasks) for example.  This solves my immediate problem, but does anyone know if `update_idletasks` ever works on the Mac?