# In tkinter GUI what are pending events and idle callbacks?

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

I wanted to know what are pending events and idle callbacks because everywhere on the internet it is written that window.update() gets pending events and idle callbacks up to date, and I cannot understand the meaning of this.

Comment: some good information about the methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158811/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-update-idletasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
some_widget.configure(background="red")
```

When this code executes, the change won't happen immediately. Instead, the change is added to a queue of idle events. These events don't get processed until the next time something processes events on the queue.

Similarly, if you do something like `root.after(1000, some_function)`, the call to `some_function` is added to the idle queue and won't be processed until something processes the idle queue and at least 1000ms have elapsed.

Now, consider a canvas that does things when you click on it. If you click on it three times in rapid succession, tkinter can only process one event at a time. While it's processing the first click, the other two are *pending*. They are in the queue but won't actually get processed until either `update` is called, or the code returns control to `mainloop`.