# Is it possible to view/print to console the idle queue in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

In reference to [In tkinter GUI what are pending events and idle callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70745332/12664040) question, which asks what are pending events and idle callbacks in tkinter, I was wondering if there is a way to print the event/idle queue to console or a tracelog.

The only potential solution I could come up with is the code below, but I was wondering if there was an easier way.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# Some widgets
for foo in range(5):
    tk.Button(root, text="Press Me!").pack()

# Bind all widgets to print events
widgets = root.winfo_children()
def event_print(event):
    print(event)

events = [
    "<Button>",
    "<Motion>",
    "<ButtonRelease>",
    "<Double-Button>",
    "<Enter>",
    "<Leave>",
    "<FocusIn>",
    "<FocusOut>",
    "<Return>",
    "<Key>",
    "<Shift-Up>",
    "<Configure>",
]

for widget in widgets:
    for event in events:
        widget.bind(event, event_print)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've been using tk for a couple of decades and never once needed to know what was in the event queue. Can you give an example of why you think this information would be useful?

Comment: I wanted to use it as a learning tool for how tk processes events/what events actually occur during the running of tk. But as for a practical use I don't see one, was more for curiousities sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to print the event/idle queue to console or a tracelog.

No, there is not. At least, not without writing your own code in C that hooks into the underlying tcl interpreter.

The solution you propose in your question wouldn't work 100% either. There are many events that get added to the queue by the tk library itself.

Comment: Makes sense, yeah I didn't think my example was a good solution, just the only one I could come up with. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've only been using Tk for a couple months, and I came upon a strange need to do just this. I am using a MouseWheel binding to generate events for scrolling functionality. On Linux, or maybe just something particular to my Linux system, it so happens that the MouseWheel `event.delta` attribute is not populated. Therefore, there is no information about MouseWheel velocity or rotational angle, and each event can only be interpreted as a single step in either positive or negative direction. Although the latency in my ad hoc UI is not unreasonable given my lack of experience, playing out the scrolling as a series of single steps has revealed its improfessional origins.

Therefore, what I would like to do is count the number `n` of queued MouseWheel events, and then implement them all at once in a single call to the callback function.

As noted above, this is not possible, at least from the python level where I am at.

I have been forced to come up with an awkward workaround. I can handle the MouseWheel events one by one, and do nothing but keep a running tally of the subtotal - no GUI update, just exit the callback immediately. This carries no latency penalty. However, in the aborted callback function I also `event_generate` a virtual event with `when='tail'`, which will run the full callback only after the complete sequence of pending MouseWheel events has been handled. This virtual event callback now applies the final tally of MouseWheel events to update the GUI, all in one step.