# Wait on tkinter entry validation on focusout before processing the value

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, customtkinter

For a project using customtkinter i have to implement input validation on an `entry` widget without using `invalidcommand` since this is not imlemented. However, since I validate the entry with `focusout`, I have the problem that clicking on the button alone does not cause a focus removal from the entry. If I set the focus on the button manually, the validation is triggered, but the rest of the button code is executed first. The behavior can be reproduced by the sample below:

```py
from customtkinter import CTk, CTkEntry, CTkButton, ThemeManager, StringVar
from re import compile


class ValidatedCTkEntry(CTkEntry):
    def __init__(self, master, reset_value, pattern, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,
                         validate='focusout',
                         validatecommand=(master.register(self.validate_ap), '%P'),
                         *args, **kwargs,)
        self.is_valid = True
        self.res_val = reset_value
        self.pattern = pattern

    # The validation function:
    def validate_ap(self, inp):
        if not self.pattern.match(inp):
            self._textvariable.set(self.res_val)
            self.after_idle(lambda: self.configure(validate='focusout'))
            self.configure(text_color='red')
            self.is_valid = False
        else:
            self.configure(text_color=ThemeManager.theme["CTkEntry"]["text_color"])
            self.is_valid = True
        return self.is_valid


class App(CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.var = StringVar()
        # The entry to be validated:
        self.entry = ValidatedCTkEntry(self, textvariable=self.var, width=80,
                                       pattern=compile(r'^(?!0+$)022\d{5}$'),
                                       reset_value='02200000')
        self.entry.pack()
        # The Button to start the processing of the entry information
        self.btn = CTkButton(self, text='process', command=self.print_if_valid)
        self.btn.pack()

    # The function that handles the correct input further
    def print_if_valid(self):
        self.btn.focus_set()  # set focus on btn to remove it from entry and trigger validation
        if self.entry.is_valid:  # this code runs before the validate_ap validation
            print(self.var.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

How can I force the validation to be executed first and then the rest of the button code?

**EDIT:**

Inserting an `update()` command just after `focus_set()` on the entry seems to do the trick. However, regarding this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158811/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-update-idletasks) I am unsure if this is a good practice... `update_idletasks` does not yield the desired effect.